プログラムにおけるエフェクトとはどういう意味ですか？
以下の動画の 8:00 あたりで「いま throws と async という２つのエフェクトしかないんですけど、今後、なんらかのエフェクトが追加されたときにエフェクトなのか型なのか区別できなくなる」 という発言がありました。
iOSDC Japan 2024: Swift 6のTyped throwsとSwiftにおけるエラーハンドリングの全体像を学ぶ - YouTube
似たような単語として、サイドエフェクト（副作用）がありますが、どうやらサイドエフェクト（副作用）とは別の意味な気がします。
エフェクトとはどういうものなのでしょうか？（throwsやasyncがどのような動きをするのかは理解しています）

余談ですが（？）、OCamlにはEffect handlersというものもあるようです（Effect handlersという単語を聞いたことがる程度）

追記：
Swiftの言語仕様を決める下記の部分のことを言っていると思うので、一般的な（？）もしくはSwift特有（？）の言い回しだと思います。
https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0413-typed-throws.md

If E were an effect name in some later Swift version, then there is an ambiguity between typed throws and that effect that we would need to resolve. Future effect modifiers might require more than one argument (and therefore need parentheses), which would make them inconsistent with throws E.


こういった場合はまず発言主 = 動画のコメント欄で聞くのが優先すべき気がします。

@cubick 追記しました

質問に紹介されたドキュメントだと Source compatibility の説明くらいから effect という単語が出てきているようですが。the effect of typed throws can then ripple to its callers., Effect on API resilience, Effect on ABI stabilityなど。そして提示された文は Thrown error type syntax の一部ですね。その辺を読解してみれば良いのでは？

@kunif その文書の Effect on API resilience の部分は普通の英単語としての "effect" であり、単に影響のことを指しています。同じリポジトリの他のプロポーザルにも書かれている言い回しです。

@cubick この動画はカンファレンスのトークの録画であり、このチャンネルはカンファレンスの主催のチャンネルなので、この動画にコメントするのが効果的な聞き方なのかは微妙かもな……とは思いました。個人的には、どこかで聞いた聞き慣れない専門用語について質問するのはスタック・オーバーフローの使い方としてアリな気はしています。特定の発話のみを気にしているのなら話者に直接伺えないか並行して考えるのもアリですが、今回はそれだけではない登場箇所も書かれていましたし。

ここでいうエフェクトとは、いわゆる computational effects のことです。厳密には不正確であることを承知で大雑把に言うと、プログラムの関数を実行して計算するときに行われる計算以外の物事のことを指します。Swift に限らずプログラミング言語一般で使える専門用語で、コンピュータ科学の用語です。
たとえば、整数たちが入っているとても長い配列を受け取って、それらを全部足した結果を返すようなプログラムを書き、関数 sum_of_integers として実装したとしましょう。プログラムとして書かれたこの関数のことを、整数の列を受け取って整数を返す、数学的な意味での関数とほとんど同じものだと解釈することはできます。一方で、もしかすると関数 sum_of_integers は、「計算を開始しました」「計算が終了しました」というようなログを標準出力に出しているかもしれません。あるいはもしかすると、内部で並列処理を使って効率的に足し算をしているかもしれません。足し算の結果がプログラムでは扱えないほど大きなものだった場合に例外を出す実装になっているときもあるでしょう。このような物事は、数学的な意味での関数としては解釈しきれないものです。このようなものを副作用 (side-effects) と言ったり、もう少し広い意味で computational effects と言ったりしています。より厳密には、プログラミング言語の意味論を考えているときに出てくる言葉です。
自分は Swift には詳しくありませんが、今回参照なさっている言語機能と構文においては、検査例外 (throws) と非同期処理 (async) のことをエフェクトの例として扱っているようです。関数定義の構文において、その関数が検査例外を持つという修飾子と非同期的に動くという修飾子は、どちらも計算そのものにはあまり関係ありません。そのことをもってエフェクトとして扱っているのでしょう。問題の動画においては、ここで更に修飾子の種類が増えた場合に関数定義の構文規則が曖昧性を持つ可能性について言及している訳です。
ところで、関数が何を計算するかについて型システムで管理するように、関数がどんなエフェクトを持っているのかについて管理するエフェクトシステムというものが考えられます。どのようにして管理するかについてはいくつかのやり方が提案されており、そのひとつが algebraic effects and handlers です。OCaml の言語機能である effect handlers はコレに関係しています。ここでは詳細な説明は省きます。
参考

Effect system -- Wikipedia（英語版）
Side effect -- Wikipedia（英語版）
Effects bibliography


プログラムでエフェクトという言葉は使いません。
それこそ、それを言っている人に聞くのがいいかと思います。

質問に追記しました
